# problem in threading c++

Tags: c++

i am running 2 threads and the text i display first is displayed after the execution of thread

```
string thread(string url)
{
    mutex.lock();
    //some function goes here 
    mutex.unlock();
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"asd";

    boost::thread t1(boost::bind(&thread)); 
    boost::thread t2(boost::bind(&thread));

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

in the main program i have just displayed an text `asd` this displayed always after the execution of the thread ..

Comment: how about adding a flush after "asd" e.g. cout<<"asd" << flush

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::cout << "asd" << std::flush;
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `cout` is buffered, data put to it may not appear immediately on the console (or wherever it may be redirected to). Thus, try flushing the output stream within the thread. E.g.

```
cout << "asd" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on your original post (not enough posts yet); on a tangential note, consider using scoped_lock (if you're not already!), safer than explicit lock/unlock calls...

also one word of caution, flush is expensive, call only when necessary.